# How do I disable netbeans from formatting double {{curly braces}} as javascript/angular?

Tags: netbeans

I am using netbeans and laravel. When I auto-format, it breaks php code within blade templates.

Larvel's blade template uses {{}}, and I have PHP code inside the braces. I really didn't care that netbeans doesn't have blade support, or that it thought it was javascript, until now. But I can't have it breaking my php.

```
//before auto format
{{$errors->has("x")}}

//after auto format
{{$errors -  >has("x")}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try following:

1. go to Tools|Plugins -> Installed
2. check the "Show details"
3. find AngularJS Editor and check its check box on the left
4. press Deactivate button

This will also remove syntax highlighting though...

Comment: Thats a good trick, but how will this affect a html with angular js code in it ?